# permissionOverwrites not working properly while creating channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

While creating I'd like to deny the `VIEW_CHANNEL` permission for the @everyone role. While creating the channel it doesn't work. However after handling the promise using `permissionOverwrites.edit` does work. Does anyone why it behaves this weird. I've included the code below:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    let guild = message.guild;
    if(message.content === '.raid'){
        const ch = guild.channels.create(`${message.member.displayName}\'s raid`, {
            type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
            parent: state.categories.raids,
            userLimit:50,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    //@everyone ID
                    //This does not work.
                    id: state.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
             },
         ],
        }).then(channel => {
            //This works
            client.channels.cache.get(channel.id).permissionOverwrites.edit(state.roles.everyone, {VIEW_CHANNEL : false});
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you logged `state.roles.everyone` to confirm it returns a Snowflake

Comment: @Elitezen it indeed returns the expected value